# vim command on top of window

Tags: vim, ide

I code in python and C++ regularly and vim is my editor of choice. I have a bunch of plugins/snippets that make things a lot easier. One feature I lack is the ability to move the command window of vim on top. So, if I type ":e ", I want this command to be on top of the window. How do I do that?

Comment: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Can-I-move-command-line-to-the-top-td1174202.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command-line is always at the bottom; this cannot be changed. I guess the reason is that some Ex commands (like `:ls`) print multiple lines of output. You would expect this output to be next to / close to the command itself. A command-line on top would mean that the normal window layout of Vim would "scroll down" to make space for the output. This is unnatural and not like terminals work. (vi / Vim is first and foremost a terminal application!)

So, get used to it!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand the this would be weird on a terminal, but gvim has moved way beyond terminal. The number of times, I open new files (or) do something in the command-line is so many that it would be great to have this feature (at least in gvim)

Comment: The design philosophy of Vim is to strive for feature parity in all versions, GUI and console; you should be able to switch between them without losing much functionality. Cp. `:help design-multi-platform`